# Why can't String.replace() tell the difference between null and "null"?

Tags: javascript

So I stumbled upon this while debugging some weird incidents at work where the strings contained "null" in the text:

```
"Some string containing testnull in the text".replace(null, "REPLACER")
"> Some string containing testREPLACER in the text"
```

while

```
"Some string containing testnull in the text".replace(undefined, "REPLACER")
"> Some string containing testnull in the text"
```

Comment: The first parameter is converted to a string. Try it with `"Some string containing testundefined in the text".replace(undefined, "REPLACER")` or `"Some string containing test1,2,3 in the text".replace([1, 2, 3], "REPLACER")`

Comment: I actually tested it in the scenario where the bug was present, and it worked without replacing "undefined". But now, when I test it in the console it replaces undefined too, just as you say. :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the documentation for [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> Syntax
>
> ```
>  const newStr = str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubstr|function)
> ```
>
> **regexp (pattern)**
>   A RegExp object or literal. The match or matches are replaced with newSubstr or the value returned by the specified function.
>
> **substr**
>   A String that is to be replaced by newSubstr. It is treated as a literal string and is not interpreted as a regular expression. Only the first occurrence will be replaced.

The first argument needs to be a regular expression or a string.

`null` isn't either, so it is automatically typecast. If you convert `null` to a string, you get `"null"`.

```js
const a = "" + null;
const b = "null";

console.log(a === b);
```

Answer (score -1):

> null is a language keyword that evaluates to a special value that is
>   usually used to indicate the absence of a value. Using the **typeof
>   operator on null returns the string “object”**, indicating that null
>   can be thought of as a special object value that indicates “no
>   object”.
>
> The undefined value is also the return value of functions that do not
>   explicitly return a value and the value of function parameters for
>   which no argument is passed. undefined is a predefined global constant
>   (not a language keyword like null, though this is not an important
>   distinction in practice) that is initialized to the undefined value.
>   If you apply the **typeof operator to the undefined value, it returns
>   “undefined”**, indicating that this value is the sole member of a
>   special type.

[javascript: the definitive Guide, 7th ed]

Note the following.

```
typeof null          //=> "object"
typeof undefined     //=> "undefined"
null == undefined    //=>  true
null === undefined   //=> false
null.toString()      //=> "null"
undefined.toString() //=> TypeError
```

So, in your case, the null is type-converted to string while undefined can't be done so. 
Hence you got that result.

Comment: _“while undefined can't be done so”_ — Try `"undefined".replace(undefined, "1")`, please. Then, try `null.toString()` once more. It does _not_ yield `"null"`. You missed the first comment on the question. This is completely unrelated to `typeof` (and furthermore, the “Definitive Guide” is misleading here; `null` is the only value of the _Null_ type and `typeof` is buggy). `replace` essentially checks for `typeof` `"string"` or `instanceof RegExp`. If it’s none of those it’ll essentially call `String(value)`.